# How insert in compra

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Code:

```
@staticmethod
def cadastrar_compra(compra_data):
    try:
        cliente = session.query(Cliente).filter_by(nome=compra_data['nome_cliente']).one_or_none()
        livro = session.query(Livro).filter_by(id=compra_data['id_livro']).one_or_none()
        compra = Compra(
            id_cliente=compra_data['id_cliente'],
            quantidade = compra_data['quantidade']
        )
        compra.cliente=cliente

        compra.livros.append(livro)
  
        session.add(compra)
        session.commit()
        session.close()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
```

models:

```
Base = declarative_base()


metadata = MetaData()

class Cliente(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cliente'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nome = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    compras = relationship('Compra', back_populates='cliente', cascade='all, delete')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Cliente : {self.nome}>'


if 'cliente' not in metadata.tables:
    association_table = Table(
        'compra_livro',
        Base.metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('compra_id', Integer, ForeignKey('compra.id')),
        Column('livro_id', Integer, ForeignKey('livro.id')),
        extend_existing=True
    )


class Livro(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'livro'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nome = Column(String(255))
    autor = Column(String(255))
    editora = Column(String(255))
    compras = relationship('Compra', secondary=association_table, back_populates='livros')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Livro : {self.id}, autor:{self.autor}, editora:{self.editora}>'


class Compra(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'compra'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_cliente = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("cliente.id"))
    quantidade = Column(Integer())
    cliente = relationship('Cliente', back_populates='compras')
    livros = relationship('Livro', secondary=association_table, back_populates='compras')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Compra : {self.id} {self.id_cliente}

 


how resove this problem
```